# Can I Use DFT To Find The Most Common Frequency?

Tags: time-series, frequency, fourier-transform

I have a collection of data which measures the change in state of a device which records information. I basically record the time a new observation is made on the device. I want to collect the data into groups of working times (i.e. when the device is on and working vs when it takes a break due to inactivity).

(note: there are actually a few devices that work at different rates, and I can't just hardcode a value that says a certain time difference counts as work and another counts as a break since there is actually some variability in how long it takes a device to record information).

End result, if a device is either working too slowly or not working at all, I want to be able to flag it and turn it off.

I was thinking:

1. Calculate the `diff(times)` and then basically rank those times by saying everything outside the 99% percentile counts as work and the rest counts as rest state. (The problem here is I would like to be able to classify times into actual groups of working rates -- `i.e. this device was working well at these times, slower at these times, resting at these times, and is way to slow but not resting at these other times`)
2. Treat the problem like a dsp problem: apply a DFT to the times and then look at the largest amplitudes to see which frequencies are the most common and ... (something I haven't thought of??)
3. I dont' know.

Does this problem seem familiar to anyone? Does anyone have better suggestions?

Comment: Using an abbreviation in the title of your topic---one that many persons like myself have never heard of---is unlikely to get the response you want.  I don't know `dsp` either.